# Text of an anchor tag is attached to the top of its box (Firefox only)

Tags: css

I'm currently confused by the behaviour of text inside an anchor tag, which seems to only occur on Firefox.
The text sticks to the top of its own box and therefore the text is not vertically aligned when I add a border around the text to let it look like a button.

Here is a minimal example of my usecase:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: grid;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      background-color: #e4e7ed
    }
    
    div {
      margin: 0 20%;
      padding: 2em;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    a {
      border: 1px solid #FF6600;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      background: transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FF6600;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      background-color: #FF6600;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quos nihil vero.
    </p>
    <a href="google.de">
   Click this button
  </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here you can see, that the text is at the top of its own box in Firefox
[image]

whereas in Chrome it seems to be centered:
[image]

Is this a correct behaviour? Am I overlooking a CSS property?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same font in all browsers?

Comment: try adjusting the line height line-height: 1em;

Comment: @MrLister: Yes. I updated my example and defined the font explicitly.

Comment: @MoneerKamal: It seems that this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property:

```
a {
  border: 1px solid #FF6600;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6600;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gse18n60/

You can adjust line-height based on your font-size.

Comment: Thanks, for this hint. Works for me.
Now I only have to figure out why setting the line height doesn't have the same effect in my real project. Was playing around with it before, but discarded it because there was no effect.

Comment: @j0weiss This could be because some other CSS rule was overriding it.